IR5 visa refusal to USA
I had a IR5 visa refusal[the reason for refusal was section 212[a][6][c]i. I am Canada citizen-may I visited USA short period?

INA 212(a)(6)(C)(i) is a lifetime ban for fraud or misrepresentation of a material fact. If you wish to enter the US as a nonimmigrant, you would need to get a nonimmigrant waiver. As a Canadian citizen, you would apply for a nonimmigrant waiver by filing form I-192. Note that even if you have a waiver for the ban, the immigration officer at entry still has the discretion to deny you entry for failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, and there is no waiver for that.
